# Haskell - replicate elements in a list

Tags: haskell

I want to write a Haskell program that replicates the elements of a list a given number of times. 
Here's my code:

```
repli :: [a] -> a -> [a]
repli xs n = foldl1 (\x -> take n (repeat x)) xs
```

My problem is I get the following errors when compiling:

> 'take' is applied to too many arguments
>
> couldn't match expected type '[a]->[a]' with actual type '[[a]]'

Comment: From your code, it seems that you want `repli [1,2] 2` to generate `[1,1,2,2]`, and not `[1,2,1,2]`. Is that right? Please clarify this in your question, since answers below sometimes chose the second interpretation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type signature for `foldl1` is:

```
foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

Hence, the first argument needs to be a function of two arguments. The lambda expression you're passing only takes one argument. You probably meant to do something like this:

```
repli :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
repli xs n = concat $ map (\x -> take n (repeat x)) xs
```

Or, to do it better, you can use the `replicate` function:

```
repli :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
repli xs n = concat $ map (replicate n) xs
```

Or, to do it even betterer, you can use the `[]` monad:

```
repli :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
repli xs n = xs >>= replicate n
```

Comment: `concat $ map f xs` is equivalent to the aptly named `concatMap f xs`, so you can make that reduction as well.

Answer (score 3):

How about this very simple line:

```
repli ::  [a] -> Int -> [a]
repli xs n = concat (replicate n xs)
```

Comment: Yup. Then as an exercise, write your own versions of `replicate` and `concat`. Feel free to use library functions to write those two, but then as an exercise, write your versions of those :-P.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Prelude `replicate` before rolling out your own function: http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/replicate_f.html

```
repli xs n = foldr (++) [] (replicate n xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "take" and "repeat". You also need to provide a base case where the list is empty.

```
repli [] _ = []
repli (x:xs) y = take y (repeat x) ++ repli xs y
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that worked for me

```
f :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
f n arr = concatMap (\num -> replicate n num) arr
```